# Firebase HTTP function CORS

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm still having problems with CORS when using Firebase HTTP functions.

Here is my web console error:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The 
response had HTTP status code 404.
```

Here is my function:

```
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
const express = require('express');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const app = express();
const validate_user = require('./validate_user_id_token.js');
const charge_card = async(req, res) => {
  // ...
}

app.use(cors);
app.use(validate_user);
app.use(charge_card);

exports.foo = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I think I've read over every single Firebse CORS question. I also have a near replica of the sample provided [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js).

Please help :)

Edit:
The URL I am calling is correct (used texdiff.com just to be sure, and functions logs are showing it as executed but returning 404). For reasons unknown, a 404 is returned regardless. Perhaps that is CORS mechanism?

Update:
I got things working without using express by putting using `cors()` in my onRequest handler:

```
exports = module.exports = functions.https.onRequest(async(req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {});
    await charge_card(req, res);
});
```

Not ideal, but it works for now :/

Comment: Read the error message. "The response had HTTP status code 404." You just got the URL wrong.

Comment: @Quentin No, it's correct. I checked that already, it seems that there will be a 404 even if the URL is correct. I will update the post.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Firebase documentation, there are a couple of references to CORS configuration:

***Using CORS:***

You can [enable the use of CORS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#use_middleware_modules_with) by calling it within the function, just like you did in your update to the question:

```
// Usage of the `cors` express middleware
return cors(req, res, () => {
  // TO-DO
});
```

Also if you have an already existing Express app, [you can then enable CORS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_existing_express_apps) by doing:

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
```

This is what you had already done on the first step, but there's the difference in the `{ origin: true }` definition, so maybe that is related.

In any case, as per the documentation it looks like it is indeed fine to add the `cors` within the request.