# Enable Cors for Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, cors, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to enable [cors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for my http Cloud Functions. However, even when following [this example that uses cors](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/time-server/functions/index.js), when trying to [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), it still gives me the error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Here is my cloud function:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});

exports.foo = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    return cors(req, res, () => {
        let format = req.query.format;
        if (!format) {
            format = req.body.format;
        }

        //do stuff

    });
});
```

And here is how I fetch:

```
fetch("https://us-central1-my-database.cloudfunctions.net/foo", {
    method: "POST", 
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}).then((res) => {
    // ...
}).catch((err) => {
    // ...
});
```

Why isn't cors working, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try to give a look at this case: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49178210/firebase-http-function-cors) that is very similar and it has an answer explaining how you can enable CORS on Firebase Cloud functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use cors with its [default parameters](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) which are

```
{
    "origin": "*",
    "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    "preflightContinue": false,
    "optionsSuccessStatus": 204
}
```

In your case you just need to change a single line:

```js
// code...

// const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const cors = require('cors')();

// code...
```