# Nest and HTTP function - CORS

Tags: firebase, cors, google-cloud-functions, nestjs

I'm trying to utilize Nest with a Firebase HTTP function, but am hitting a CORS error when calling from the client.

This was my setup before:

```
declare const require: any
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true })
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
app.use(cors)
const cb = (req, res) => res.status(200).send('success')
app.use(cb)

export default functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

The above worked fine (with a Cloud Functions Invoker role set with `allAuthenticatedUsers`).

This is my new setup with Nest:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core'
import { ExpressAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-express'
import { Api_Module } from './api.module'
import express from 'express'

const server = express()

const create_nest_server = async (express_instance: express.Express) => {
  const adaptor = new ExpressAdapter(express_instance)
  const app = await NestFactory.create(Api_Module, adaptor)
  app.enableCors({ origin: true })
  await app.init()
  return app
}


create_nest_server(server)
    .then(v => console.log('Nest Ready'))
    .catch(err => console.error('Nest broken', err))


export default functions.https.onRequest(server)
```

(from https://fireship.io/snippets/setup-nestjs-on-cloud-functions/)

This yields `Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-<project>.cloudfunctions.net/api-default/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.` on the client.

I've also tried a couple other things such as:

```
declare const require: any
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true })

const server = express()
server.use(cors)
// ...the rest
```

And:

```
const create_nest_server = async (express_instance: express.Express) => {
  const adaptor = new ExpressAdapter(express_instance)
  const app = await NestFactory.create(Api_Module, adaptor, {
    cors: {
      origin: true,
    }
  })

  app.enableCors()
  await app.init()
  return app
}
```

And:

```
  const nestApp = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, adapter, {
    logger: new CoreLogger(),
    cors: {
      origin: '*',
      methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
      credentials: true,
      preflightContinue: false,
      optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
    },
  })
```

As well as using `app.enableCors()` without any arguments.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @skwny can you check the solution provided [here](https://www.joshmorony.com/an-introduction-to-nestjs-for-ionic-developers/) and verify if it helps you? It seems to be a different approach to the ones you tested.

Comment: @gso_gabriel thanks for the link but that's not a Firebase functions integration example. I did try to utilize `app.enableCors()` during nest app boostrap as seen in that link but did not have success with it unfortunately.

Comment: Take a look at [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49274135/10810527). I think it may be helpful.

Comment: @Ajordat I have already seen that post, and it is also not a nest-functions an example

Comment: It IS a Firebase Function using JS which seems to be what you need. Have you checked the [suggested documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#use_middleware_modules_with) shown in there?

Comment: @Ajordat please re-read my last comment and the title of my post. I'm looking for information on how to address cors when implementing **NestJS** in firebase functions. The documentation and other SO answers do not provide this. I've tried different variations of implementing cors support based on those materials, and nothing has worked. If you have a Nest example or information, please provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your client is an Angular app, if you are running a local development version of your client, you could use a proxy config file to make your requests appear as if they're coming from the same origin:

proxy.conf.json

```
{
    "/api-default": {
        "target": "https://us-central1-<project>.cloudfunctions.net",
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

You'll need to configure this file according to how you are calling your api, then start your local app with the following command: `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

An alternative would be to add the appropriate CORS response headers in your NestJS responses:

```
@Post()
@Header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200')
create() {
  return 'This action adds a new cat';
}
```

This would tell the client that that the server allows the provided origin.